# os.system() works but subprocess.popen() doesnt... FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] and OSError: [WinError 193] errors

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, subprocess

I am getting a strange error when I try to run a simple subprocess line. I often get a "OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application" on the computer that I need the program to work on even though the same lines of code work on a different computer to open up a random text file. When I use os.system([path]) it works but I need the code to continue and not wait to be closed out.
Here is an example of what I am getting

```
import subprocess
import os

open = subprocess.Popen('C://Users//z004c50a//Desktop//Thisworksfolder//thisWorks3.txt')
#open = os.system('C://Users//z004c50a//Desktop//Thisworksfolder//thisWorks3.txt')
```

**Output:**

Using os.system works but pauses the code so I want to use subprocess method but that gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\z004c50a\Desktop\PythonApplication2\PythonApplication2\PythonApplication2.py", line 4, in <module>
    open = subprocess.Popen('C://Users//z004c50a//Desktop//Thisworksfolder//thisWorks3.txt')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I have tried a lot of variations with `stdout = subprocess.pipe, shell = True`, etc.

Another program that works elsewhere and not on the computer I need it to work...

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
#Iterate through path objects, find all that end with .txt

#This is the intial loop that
for item in p.glob('**/*'):
   
    if item.suffix in (['.txt']):
        name = item.name
        path = Path.resolve(item).parent
        size = item.stat().st_size
        modified = datetime.fromtimestamp(item.stat().st_mtime)

        files.append(File(name, path, size, modified))
        pathName =  '"' + str(path) + '\\' + str(name) + '"'
        updateFile.write("\n" + pathName)
        print(pathName)
        open = subprocess.call(pathName) #open the file
        #open = os.system(pathName) #open the file
        sys.exit()
```

**Output:**

```
"C:\Users\z004c50a\Desktop\ThisWorksfolder\thisWorks3.txt"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\z004c50a\Desktop\PythonCadMigration\PythonCadMigration\PythonCadMigration.py", line 71, in <module>
    open = subprocess.call(pathName) #open the file
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 339, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
Press any key to continue . . .
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

When I set the shell to true `subprocess.Popen('C://Users//z004c50a//Desktop//Thisworksfolder//thisWorks3.txt', shell = True)`, I get an error **FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]** which is even weirder because if I enter that path into cmd then it opens like normal so I know that the file is there. Here is an example

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("dir", shell =True)
```

**Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\z004c50a\Desktop\PythonCadMigration\PythonCadMigration\PythonCadMigration.py", line 32, in <module>
    subprocess.run("dir", shell =True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 488, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Press any key to continue . . .
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I have checked my paths and do not believe that is the issue but I am very open to any help on the problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've only used `subprocess.Popen` once, but it's working.

```
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'wintest.py'])
```

it looks like the first `arg` accepted should be a list with the file path in the second index.